# How to fix cy.route() data type response issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cypress

I try to use Cypress.io cy.route() to manage the behaviour of network requests.
A stub was wrtitten to replace the network behaviour of the application to test the UI.

The expected results is for the backend to return a string-typed response in JSON format. 
Quotes or double quotes should not appear outside of the bracket.

An example of the expected result:

```
{"mockdata":"mock"}
```

However, my App kept returning object-typed response during the test,
such as

```
{mockdata:"mock"}
```

How to make Mock API to return string-typed response? Thank you.

Attached below are my test codes:

```
context('mock API', function () {
    before(function () {
        cy.server()
        cy.route({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/category/menu',
            response: '{"mockdata":"mock"}'
        }).as('rootBlock')

    }
    it('use mock API', function () {
        cy.visit('/')
        cy.wait('@rootBlock')
    })

}
```

And the sample code of my APP using JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/category/menu',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (json) {
        console.log(typeof json)
          // Expect String to be returned
          // but it always return as Object during a cypress test
        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(json).mockdata
          // throwing errors...
    }
});
```

And my system is: Win7 x64

node.js: v10.14.1

Cypress.io: v3.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mock tries to automatically cast your response into a JSON object (has it should be).

If you want to return a string, you should stringify your object :

`response: JSON.stringify({"mockdata":"mock"})` should works.

Also you may add an header property with :

```
header: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
},
```

but it should not be mandatory in your case

You can also check the documentation there : 
[https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Function)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response! I updated the header property and it worked! Huge thanks to you <3